# Applying a function with logical tests to a numpy array

Tags: arrays, function, boolean

I have a function that is defined piecewise over different regions. If I feed the function a single value it works, but when I try it with an array I get the error with my Boolean operators.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

```
#numérique
import numpy as np

#maniupulation des données
import pandas as pd

#généner des graphiques
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ap_poly(x):
    if ((x>0.1) and (x<4.1)):
        a1 = -10.52866
        a2 = 2.897589
        a3 = 0.155439
        a4 = 0.012134
        a5 = 0.032469
        a6 = -0.01700
        a7 = -0.007715



        y=np.exp(a1+a2*np.log(x)+a3*(np.log(x))**2+a4*(np.log(x))**3+a5*(np.log(x))**4+a6*(np.log(x))**5+a7*(np.log(x))**6)



        return y



    elif ((x>=4.1) and (x<17.5)):

        a1 = 12.2989721
        a2 = -62.6817877
        a3 = 76.8567527
        a4 = -46.5409791
        a5 = 15.4668540
        a6 = -2.69704827
        a7 = 0.19320089


        y=np.exp(a1+a2*np.log(x)+a3*(np.log(x))**2+a4*(np.log(x))**3+a5*(np.log(x))**4+a6*(np.log(x))**5+a7*(np.log(x))**6)



        return y
    
    
    elif ((x>=17.5) and (x<187)):



        a1 = -2.75837754173
        a2 = 0.84486512587
        a3 = -4.54429428312
        a4 = 3.13777287014
        a5 = -0.55002150873
        a6 = -0.12583882143
        a7 = 0.06299457091
        a8 = -0.00902755312
        a9 = 0.00045531915

        y=np.exp(a1+a2*np.log(x)+a3*(np.log(x))**2+a4*(np.log(x))**3+a5*(np.log(x))**4+a6*(np.log(x))**5+a7*(np.log(x))**6+a8*(np.log(x))**7+a9*(np.log(x))**8)



        return y

ap_poly(0.11)

#make evenly log space set of points
T_ap_poly=np.logspace(0.11,186,500)
C_ap_poly=ap_poly(T_ap_poly)
plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
# plotting the value of x_input and y_input using loglog plot
plt.loglog(T_ap_poly, C_ap_poly)
```

I tried to add any() around the Boolean tests but that did not really help, just changed the error.

Comment: I guess I have to use np.picewise as in https://www.pythonpool.com/numpy-piecewise/